# Installing plugins from Linux eclipse into a Windows instance with p2 director

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I'm using the p2 director on Linux to install plugins into the Linux Eclipse instance and into Windows instance as well. The Linux one works well, but I struggle with the Windows. I tried few arguments (or without) and tried few different repositories/plugins to install, but I still end up with the same error:

`Installing org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 9.4.0.201712051550.
Installation failed.
An error occurred while installing the items
 session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.google.gson 2.7.0.v20170129-0911, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
 Error while loading manipulator.`

For example, I start with plain Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary 4.7.1a and I'm trying to install CDT 9.3 on top of it (but this problem applies to other plugins as well).

I set my repositories (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen,http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.3) and artefacts (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group) accordingly and then run following:

`./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -roaming -repository $PLUGIN_REPOSITORIES -installIU $PLUGIN_ARTEFACTS -destination ../../scWindows/eclipse -bundlepool ../../scWindows/eclipse -p2.os win32 -p2.ws win32 -p2.arch x86_64`

Is there an argument I'm missing or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Just noticed that the p2 director is outputing cdt 9.4 version even when i'm poiting it to 9.3 repository. The 9.4 I think is for Oxygen 2 while I'm installing it on top of Oxigen 1a

Comment: I guess CDT 9.4 works also with Oxygen.1a and if no version is specified the highest version is used. To install CDT 9.3 use the `-installIU org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group/9.3.2.201709131603`.

Comment: `-profile $PROFILE_NAME` is missing. See: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking the that pointing to the 9.3 repository it wouldn't be able to even know about anything higher than 9.3. But specifying the version sounds as good approach. Good catch. In the error message is saying the SDKProfile was used, which I'm using and in my configuration/config.ini is set the eclipse.p2.profile=SDKProfile. So when I set the -profile SDKProfile still didn't help. I upgraded to Oxygen 2 just to see if that would have effect on the issue and still issue present.

Comment: @howlger I have to say, after yesterday I started watching your YT, it's so well made, the videos are condensed, high information contraction, professionally edited, really excellent work.

Comment: CDT (9.3 and 9.4) is also contained in the Oxygen repository (the CDT 9.3 repository is here redundant). Thanks for watching my videos. Sorry for not having an answer to your question. The only difference between Linux and Windows should be `-p2.os win32 -p2.ws win32 -p2.arch x86_64`.

Comment: Good to know, either way not specifying a version is bad, I will remedy that because the final product is very sensitive to what version it is running. But at the moment I'm just learning how to use it so I was not bothering with the version. Thanks for making the videos, really good content. That's ok with the question, still learning a lot from your comments, I think I solved the problem, I will double check and verify it and post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand exactly why or how. But when I used an absolute path instead of relative paths it remedied my problem. Together with the -roaming the relative paths should be stored, so the final should be as desired, but for the moment the p2 seems to need the absolute path. I worked around it with the following:

`` sudo apt-get install realpath
WINDOWS_ABSOLUTE_PATH=`realpath ../../scWindows/eclipse`
echo $WINDOWS_ABSOLUTE_PATH ``

So in the script, I just use the variable $WINDOWS_ABSOLUTE_PATH which will get resolved as the full absolute path.

Comment: If somebody has a better way doing it, I'm open to it. But this does the job, so I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: Interesting that I was stuck on this problem for 2 days and only after posting it on SO I made some progress. The following link has some examples how to use the p2 director which might be useful to somebody https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application/Examples/Install_into_eclipse_using_SDKProfile